# Access static variables in ObjC categories

Tags: objective-c, class, static, categories

I'm trying to implement a category of an existing class.
There is a static variable in the existing class.
If I try to access the static variable from a category, I'm getting 
an error that the static variable is undeclared.

Is it possible to access static variables in ObjC Categories ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, Objective-C doesn't associate static variables with classes. Static variables are simply scoped by default to whatever file they're declared in.

To make a static variable visible in other files, add a declaration in the corresponding header file prefixed with the keyword `extern`. So for example, if you had defined the following static variable somewhere in one of your .m files

```
int seconds = 60;
```

you could then add the following declaration in the .h file:

```
extern int seconds;
```

Then, any .m file that imports that .h file will see the static variable.

Comment: thanks, so I need to subclass or add the methods to the existing class for my needs.

Comment: Not sure I followed that. Your original question seemed to be about visibility of static variables; am I misreading that? You can also add class methods in a category, if that's what you're asking. Class and instance methods, as well as C functions, can generally access static variables as long as they're in scope. There's really nothing special about that.